# Save Img with paste.image.js

Tags: javascript, php, image, save, paste

I can not customize a plugin I found.

https://redgeoff.github.io/paste-image/examples/

it generates a file img url `"blob: // local / 293843234223"` codified that even if I read it I do not know how to resume it to save it, but I do not find so much documentation and the way to save and to encode the string with php or JavaScript the image after the <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>. My intent is to have a base64 string to write in a directory.